# Формы открываются по клику на кнопки

Tags: javascript

```
            <section>
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="form">
                    <fieldset>
                      <button class="button">Добавить подписку</button>
                      <button class="button">Убрать подписку</button>
                      <button class="button">Посмотреть подписку</button>
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>
        </section>
```

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
  }
  fieldset{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    display: grid;
  }
  .container {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #563C68;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

Есть форма fieldset внутри нее кнопки, при нажатии на каждую из кнопок должно открываться индивидуальная  форма и появляться вместо предыдущей.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое можно реализовать? Необходимо использовать чистый JS

Answer (score 1):

почему бы не сделать скрытый элемент popup и повесть слушатель на кнопку при клике на которую будет classList.add добавлять класса со всплытием окна с popup

```
<button type="button" 
        aria-label="Кнопка редактирования профиля"
        class="button button_item_edit"></button>

<div class="popup popup_element_profile">
какой-то контент
</div>


.popup {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 1s, opacity .5s ease;
}

.popup_open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

const handleClick = document.querySelector('.button_item_edit')
const popupElement = document.querySelector('.popup_element_profile')

handleClick.addEventListener('click', () => popupElement.classList.add('popup_open'))
```

как-то так только свои переменные и имена классов

Answer (score 0):

Вот что я придумал, надеюсь это вам поможет
P.S : Кнопку закрытия вы можете поменять на любую иконку, изобрадения и т.д но не забудьте добавить класс btn-close

```js
const overlay = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-close");
  for(let i = 0 ; i < overlay.length; i++){
    overlay[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
    })

    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("active");
    })
  }
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
  }
  fieldset{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    display: grid;
  }
  .container {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #563C68;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .overlay{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  }

  .overlay > div{
    position: relative;
    width: 640px;
    padding: 24px;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .overlay > div h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }

  .overlay span{
    position: absolute;
    right: 24px;
    top: 24px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .active{
    display: flex;
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form">
      <fieldset>
        <button class="button">Добавить подписку</button>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div>
            <h1>Добавить подписку</h1><span class="btn-close">X</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident eaque, quo possimus corrupti accusantium ab. Quas vitae atque a temporibus labore sunt, ullam rerum eaque tenetur, quisquam quidem, officia unde.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="button">Убрать подписку</button>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div>
            <h1>Убрать подписку</h1><span class="btn-close">X</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident eaque, quo possimus corrupti accusantium ab. Quas vitae atque a temporibus labore sunt, ullam rerum eaque tenetur, quisquam quidem, officia unde.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="button">Посмотреть подписку</button>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div>
            <h1>Посмотреть подписку</h1><span class="btn-close">X</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident eaque, quo possimus corrupti accusantium ab. Quas vitae atque a temporibus labore sunt, ullam rerum eaque tenetur, quisquam quidem, officia unde.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Как же с девушками сложно).
Но я постарался и вот что получилось

```js
const btnsNext = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-next");
const btnsPrev = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-prev");

for (let i = 0; i < btnsNext.length; i++) {
  btnsNext[i].addEventListener("click", nextForm);
}

for (let i = 0; i < btnsPrev.length; i++) {
  btnsPrev[i].addEventListener("click", prevForm);
}

function nextForm() {
  this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
  this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
}

function prevForm() {
  this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
  this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: consolas;
}

form {
  width: 375px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  padding: 24px;
}

.block-form {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sub-block-form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 24px 0;
}

.sub-block-form label {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.sub-block-form input,
.sub-block-form select {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sub-block-form button,
.sub-block-form input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="block-form form-1 active">
    <h3>Шаг 1</h3>
    <div class="sub-block-form">
      <label for="firstname">Имя</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstname">
    </div>

    <div class="sub-block-form">
      <label for="lastname">Фамилия</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastname">
    </div>

    <div class="sub-block-form form-btn">
      <div class="sub-block-form-left"></div>
      <div class="sub-block-form-right"><button type="button" class="btn-next">Дальше</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block-form form-2">
    <h3>Шаг 1</h3>
    <div class="sub-block-form">
      <label for="email">Почта</label>
      <input type="email" id="email">
    </div>

    <div class="sub-block-form">
      <label for="age">Возраст</label>
      <input type="email" id="age">
    </div>

    <div class="sub-block-form">
      <label for="sex">Пол</label>
      <select value="" id="sex">
        <option value="f">Женский</option>
        <option value="m">Мужской</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="sub-block-form form-btn">
      <div class="sub-block-form-left"><button type="button" class="btn-prev">Назад</button></div>
      <div class="sub-block-form-right"><button type="button" class="btn-next">Дальше</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block-form form-3">
    <h3>Шаг 1</h3>
    <div class="sub-block-form">
      <label for="password">Пароль</label>
      <input type="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div class="sub-block-form">
      <label for="confirm-password">Повторите пароль</label>
      <input type="password" id="confirm-password">
    </div>

    <div class="sub-block-form form-btn">
      <div class="sub-block-form-left"><button type="button" class="btn-prev">Назад</button></div>
      <div class="sub-block-form-right"><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Возможно к вас были где-то созданные индивидуальные формы, но я опирался на предоставленным вами код

Comment: Нужно чтобы форма открывалась вместо другой формы, не модалкой. По принципу этого примера https://codepen.io/Web_Cifar/pen/PoNNEYY?editors=1010 
Но я не знаю как сделать чтобы с одной страницы открывалась несколько форм. Сколько не искала всюду кнопки вперед-назад

Comment: Я добавил новый код

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: а можно галочку?))

Comment: Какие тут интерестные люди вопросы задают, даже если ответ верный галочку не ставят((